Can't change icon of my tkinter eventhandler
Can't change the icon on my 2nd window who make the principal window on the taskbar cause a custom title bar.
I have make a program with a custom title bar that's work good, i have a icon in my task bar when i minimize him but the icon is the tkinter default and a iconbitmap or iconphoto can't change icon.
from tkinter import *

#? Function
def quit_app():
    root.destroy()
    event_handler.destroy()
def minimize_click():
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.state('iconic')
    event_handler.withdraw()
def on_icon_click_return_window(event):
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.state('normal')
    event_handler.deiconify()
def adjust_frame_size():
    root.update_idletasks()
    width = cross.width()
    height = cross.height()
    title_bar.config(width=width, height=height)
def on_drag_start(event):
    global drag_start_x, drag_start_y
    drag_start_x, drag_start_y = event.x, event.y
def on_drag_motion(event):
    x, y = root.winfo_pointerx() - drag_start_x, root.winfo_pointery() - drag_start_y
    root.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')

#? Variable
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.config(bg="#242727")
root.overrideredirect(True)
event_handler = Tk()
event_handler.attributes("-alpha", 0.0)
event_handler.lift()

title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#1e1e1e')
title_bar.pack(fill=X)

cross = PhotoImage(file="res/cross.png")
moins = PhotoImage(file="res/moin.png")

close_button = Button(title_bar, image=cross, bg="#1e1e1e", command=quit_app, relief='sunken', borderwidth=0)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)

minimize_button = Button(image=moins, command=minimize_click, bg="#1e1e1e", relief='sunken', borderwidth=0)
minimize_button.bind("<Map>", on_icon_click_return_window)
minimize_button.place(x=748, y=5.5)

#! Demarage
root.after(100, adjust_frame_size)

#! Mouvement de fenetre
drag_start_x = drag_start_y = 0
title_bar.bind("<Button-1>", on_drag_start)
title_bar.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

root.mainloop()


Sorry for my english ;)
Ty

You're calling Tk() more than once.  Each image (and other Tkinter object) is associated with one of those instances (the first created one, by default), and simply cannot work with widgets that are part of a different instance.  Use Toplevel() instead to create additional windows.

This answer may help if your platform is Windows.
